# Windows phone debug error 0x8004050A

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8

I wanna share this for anyone having the same issue, since I didn't find it anywhere on SO

I have an application for Windows phone 8.1 which has been tested for months.
Yesterday I started having an error every time I try to debug it.

***What I did:***

- Attach my Windows phone 8.1 Phone.
- Run debug.

***What the problem was:***

- Debug not starting
- Error 0x8004050A showing as below:
  [image]

***What I tryed:***

- Restart Visual Studio
- Restart PC

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably due to a connection between phone and PC.

I had to restart the phone and the problem solved itself.

Sometimes restarting the phone was not enough and I had to restart also the pc.

I hope this will help someone